# Building 200 robots starting with 1 robot, how?

Tags: java

I have an assignment to write a code that starts with 1 robot and I need to find out how many months it takes to get up to 200 robots.

Conditions:

Starting with 1 robot, this robot gathers materials for 2 months. With these materials it can build 3 robots, 1 robot each month. So the cycle for one robot is 5 months long. And of course the newly built robots also gathers materials for 2 months and then builds 3 robots each, and so on...

The only tip I have is that it should be done using 3 variables. 2 for each gathering month and 3 for each building month.

This is done in Java. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You also need to add what you've tried so far and in what way it isn't working.

Comment: I suggest you start by writing something simple which works and build on that until you get closer to the solution. If the program doesn't do what you expect, step through your code in a debugger.

Comment: Thanks. Well I haven't really tried anything for it. I have absolutely no clue on how to solve this.

Comment: Give it a try atleast before you ask for help. This is a great assignment in algorithm design. You would feel like a genius if you did this on your own, rather than have someone else do it! Cheers.

Comment: Some clues at least? :) I don't even know how to start that's why I asked, I'm happy to use trial&error once I know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem in an object-oriented manner.

I would create a class Robot with a public method workForAMonth() which might return a new robot or null.

The main loop would look like that (pseudo-code):

```
 create an empty List of robots
 add one robot to it
 while the list of robots has less than 200 entries
     create a new list of the newly build robots
     iterate the list of existing robots. for each robot:
          call the workForAMonth method. When it returns a robot, append it to the list of newly build robots
     append the newly build robots to the main list
     add 1 to month
 output month
```

The workForAMonth method would look like this:

```
 increment the private month counter of this robot by 1
 whe the counter is 5, set it back to 0
 when the counter is 2 or larger, return a new Robot, else return null
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it this way. But I'm not sure how to create and add objects to lists. I have created a list like this

List RobotList = new ArrayList();

How would I add something to it?

Comment: `robotList.add(newlyCreatedRobot)`

Answer (score 1):

A hint at one possible approach:

Since the smallest unit of time here is 1 month, lets have a time variable which increments 1 month at a time.

What a robot will do depends on in which month of his 5 month cycle he currently is.
So, we keep track of how many robots are in each state,

- How many robots are in their first gathering week?
- How many robots are in their second gathering week?
- How many robots are in their first building week?
- How many robots are in their second building week?
- How many robots are in their third building week?

When one month passes, how will the number of robots in the different states change? Robots will move on to the next state. Possibly (depending on their state) they will also produce a new robot. Which state will this robot be in?

Keep on looping until you have the desired amount of robots.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no clue at all, I will give you three hints:

- Forget about robots, objects, and programming stuff (at least, for the beginning) and try to think about a **function** for the number of robots over the time
- Read about **recursion**
- Read about the **fibbonacci numbers** that are closely related to your problem.

Comment: Oh and btw, I do not know about recursion and fibbonacci numbers but a math teacher was asked to find a funtcion for the increments of the robots, he couldn't :)

Comment: Oh, bad for the math teacher :-(. However, for programming, you should definitively get familiar with the concept of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Well... The solution turned out to be very simple, here it is:

```
class Robot{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int g1 = 1, g2 = 0, b1 = 0, b2 = 0, b3 = 0, month = 0, tot = 0, left, built;
    while(tot<200){
        month++;
        tot = g1 + g2 + b1 + b2 + b3;
        System.out.println("Month " + month + " materials for " + (g1 + g2) + " robots were gathered and " + (b1 + b2 + b3) + " were built \n");
        System.out.println(" Totally there's " + tot + " Robots on the moon \n \n");
        built = b1 + b2;
        left = b3;
        b3 = b2;
        b2 = b1;
        b1 = g2;
        g2 = g1;
        g1 = (left + built);
    }
}
}
```